# Anybody knows why the tooltip doesn't show up where and how I want to?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to have the value of the bar show in a div generated next to my mouse pointer using a tooltip but It's not working out. Something appears in screen, but It's not what I want neither where I want It.
I have an event of loading bars which I think might be the responsable of the problem.
Style of the div created has position: absolute;

Here's my code:

```
 // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
          const margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 150},
            width = 660 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
          
          // append the svg object to the body of the page
          const svga = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
          
          // Parse the Data
          d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/7_OneCatOneNum_header.csv").then( function(data) {
          
            data.sort((a, b) => b.Value - a.Value);
  
  
          // X axis
          const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ 0, width ])
            .domain(data.map(d => d.Country))
            .padding(0.2)
            
  
          svga.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
            .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
                .style("text-anchor", "end");
                
  
        // Add Y axis
          const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 13000])
            .range([ height, 0])
        
          svga.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .attr("class", "y-axis")
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .style("fill", "#D6D6D6"); // Cambiar "path" por "line"
                
          const div = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);
          
          // Bars
        svga.selectAll("myRect")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
              .attr("x", d => x(d.Country) )
              .attr("y", d => y(0))
              .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
              .attr("height", height - y(0) )
              .attr("fill", "#FFD31E")
              .attr("stroke", "#D6D6D6") // Color del borde
              .attr("stroke-width", 1) // Ancho del borde
              .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')

              .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
                  d3.select(this).transition()
                     .duration('50')
                     .attr("fill", "#FFE476");
                  div.transition()
                     .duration(50)
                     .style("opacity", 1);
                  div.html(d.Value)
                     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
                     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px");
                    })

              .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
                  d3.select(this).transition()
                     .duration('50')
                     .attr("fill", "#FFD31E")
                  div.transition()
                     .duration('50')
                     .style("opacity", 0)
              })

        svga.selectAll("rect")
            .transition()
            .duration(600)
            .attr("y", d => y(d.Value))
            .attr("height", d => height - y(d.Value))
            .delay((d, i) => i * 100);
            
        

        })
```

I think the bar loading event is messing It up.